# intelXDK is generating errors on simple Javascript code

Tags: javascript, cordova, intel-xdk

i have just begun cross platform cordova/phonegap mobile app development and read somewhere over stackoverflow to use intelXDK as IDE as it has built-in Emulator developed upon Ripple.
i really don't know what's going wrong and it is really discouraging for me.

intelXDK is generating error on simple Javascript code even i have restarted IDE many times.
what am I missing?

if you know some better IDE which does posses emulator, i'd really appreciate!

[image: intelXDK generating errors on simple Javascript code]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're seeing are jshint errors generated by the linter in the Brackets editor that's built into the XDK.

You can configure the jshint errors you get either by using a jshint resource file or by putting the jshint directives directly in your code (at the top of the page). Here's what I usually start out with to keep the list down to a manageable set of errors:

```
/*jslint browser:true, devel:true, white:true, vars:true */
/*global $:false, intel:false */
```

See File->Extension Manager... for more extensions that can be added. And see http://www.jshint.com/docs/ and http://jslinterrors.com/ for some documentation regarding these directives.

Comment: that may be the case but when i test it, it doesn't make difference to the listeners i have added customly?

Comment: by the way, let me ask u a thing professionally that should i continue using intelSDK or find some other tool for it? @xmnboy

Comment: If you check my profile you'll see that I work for Intel and work on the Intel XDK product, so I'm biased... but to try and answer your question: depends on your needs and the needs of your application. If you are interested in building Cordova (aka PhoneGap) apps with the XDK, I would use it. You can mix Cordova or PhoneGap CLI with the XDK, so you don't lose anything by using the XDK. If, on the other hand, if your needs are better met by writing a native app, then I would go with a native solution.

Comment: Regarding your "doesn't make difference to the listeners" question; I'm assuming what you mean is that you still get messages about references to undefined labels? If that is the case, see the /*global ... */ directive. What I gave you is just a starting point, you need to add/customize these directives to suit your source code and application structure.